# The user information is cutoff in the answer/question revision page?

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, design

https://superuser.com/revisions/51758/list

Here is a quick example of a revision list. I noticed that on the right hand side with every edit, the user names are there, but their rep/badge count is cutoff due to some formatting. This applies to all the sites and not just SU.

[alt text http://img143.imageshack.us/img143/7218/bazookacutoff.png](http://img143.imageshack.us/img143/7218/bazookacutoff.png)

Note: None of the user avatars/pics load for me as my current location blocks most scripts/ads/etc and hangs/time outs. So those icons are currently red x'd due to this.

Can anyone reproduce? Maybe I am just crazy and this is a local issue?

Win XP, IE 7.

EDIT 1: So far this is just my local issue.  Someone might get to reproduce if they somehow blocked the picture host so the icon/pictures "red x'd".

EDIT 2: Looks like at least once person reproduced under xp and IE 7:

> Win XP and IE 7 here, and I have the same issue even though the gravatars aren't blocked. – mmyers

Comment: Looks fine for me (OSX, Safari 4.0.3) Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Also fine in Chrome 2, Windows XP.

Comment: Screen shot? (That way random, et al can mark it up with hand-scrawled cartoon guys with bazookas. :) )

Comment: Ok, well I think it is related to the avatar/pics not loading. I can't post a screenshot cause most file/pic upload sites are blocked. coughgovcough

Comment: Win XP and IE 7 here, and I have the same issue even though the gravatars aren't blocked. The rep and badges are cut off about the middle of the digits.

Comment: Oh, maybe we are onto something if someone got it to re-pro.

Comment: mmyers: can you take a screenshot and edit my question?

Comment: No... *coughgovcough*

Comment: Bazooka? Which bazooka? In don't see any frigging bazooka...

Comment: Opera is all good and clear. (thud)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works with IE8. Upgrade your browser!

[alt text http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/2651/peacedove.png](http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/2651/peacedove.png)

Comment: Well thank you for the obvious answer. ;)  I will just ignore it though (as it really does not matter that much). Maybe someday the company will upgrade.

Comment: You are always welcome, Troggy :)